# Is it possible to read IMEI from emergency call dialer?

Tags: phone-app, imei, dialer-codes, emergency-calls

I am looking for the method to read IMEI from emergency call dialer, before the phone is activated. When I try *#06# it says that this is not emergency number.

Comment: On phones with removable batterys you can find the IMEI number under the batteries

Comment: On phones with non-removable batterys you can find the IMEI number on stickers.

Answer (score 1):

No. The system does a check against a list of numbers (provided by system property ril.ecclist/ro.ril.ecclist; by detecting the current country or locale) and if that doesn't match with the available numbers, it doesn't proceed with the dialing and informs the user.

Related read: [Do all Android phones come with emergency call (power button pressed thrice) feature?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203967/96277)